# which statistical test should I use: 5 schools

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

I have conducted a study in 5 schools to investigate whether use of a game could improve math performance. In each school there were two classes, one experimental (used the game) and one control (did not use the game). Within each school the classes were assigned to a treatment by chance.

My question is, which statistical test would be best to use here?
Thank you
Steven

Comment: How to measure the improvement of math performance? pre- and post- game period tests? It tests, score is 0 - 100 or 1-5?

Answer (score 0):

Chi square test is appropriate to test;

$$\tilde{\chi}^2=\frac{1}{d}\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(O_k - E_k)^2}{E_k}$$